# php/mysql - using union, how to set variable based on selected table?

Tags: php, mysql

Using the code below, I display statuses and comments, it works as desired, although I don't completely understand my own code..

I want to achieve the following: if result is from status, $link_type = status, if result is from comments, $link_type = comment

this is my attempt ($link_type is always 'status' now)

```
    $results = db_query("
    SELECT sid as ssid, created as screated, message as smessage, recipient as srecipient 
    FROM {statuses}
    WHERE created > :logout_stamp
    UNION
    SELECT sid as ssid, created as screated, comment as smessage, uid as srecipient 
    FROM {fbss_comments} fbss
    WHERE fbss.created > :logout_stamp
    ORDER BY screated DESC LIMIT 15", 
    array(':logout_stamp' => $logout_stamp))->fetchAll();

  // foreach the results
  foreach ($results as $result) {
      $user_status = user_load($result->srecipient);
      $user_comment = user_load($result->commentuid);
      $username_status = $user_status->name;
      $username_comment = $user_comment->name;
      $date_status = $result->screated;
      $date_comment = $result->commentcreated;

      if ($result->ccreated != NULL) {
        $link_type = "comment";
      }
      else {
        $link_type = "status";
      }

print '<a href="statuses/' . ($result->ssid) . '" class="notification_wrapper">' . '<b>' . $username_status . '</b>' . ' - ' . ($link_type) . ' - ' . strip_tags(substr($result->smessage,0,30)) . ' - ' . elapsed_time($date_status) . '</a>';
```

advice is much appreciated

Comment: There is no `ccreated` field in your SELECT query. May be you will like to change `created as screated` to `created as ccreated`, in your comment (2nd) query.

Comment: i've played around with this, but it looks like union 'compresses' it into one

Comment: It will you have to give unique alias to each fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this value as extra field:

```
 SELECT sid as ssid, created as screated, message as smessage, recipient as srecipient, "status" as link_type 
FROM {statuses}
WHERE created > :logout_stamp
UNION
SELECT sid as ssid, created as screated, comment as smessage, uid as srecipient,"comment" as link_type 
FROM {fbss_comments} fbss
WHERE fbss.created > :logout_stamp
ORDER BY screated DESC LIMIT 15
```

Comment: sweet! printed using: $result->link_type - works :) thanks a lot mate, learned something again

Answer (score 1):

use **st** as it return 1 for status and 2 for comment.

```
 SELECT 1 as st,sid as ssid, created as screated, message as smessage, recipient as srecipient 
    FROM {statuses}
    WHERE created > :logout_stamp
    UNION
    SELECT 2 as st sid as ssid, created as screated, comment as smessage, uid as srecipient 
    FROM {fbss_comments} fbss
    WHERE fbss.created > :logout_stamp
    ORDER BY screated DESC LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a field in your query like the below:

```
$results = db_query("
    SELECT sid as ssid, created as screated, message as smessage, recipient as srecipient, 'status' as link_type
    FROM {statuses}
    WHERE created > :logout_stamp
    UNION
    SELECT sid as ssid, created as screated, comment as smessage, uid as srecipient, 'comment' as link_type
    FROM {fbss_comments} fbss
    WHERE fbss.created > :logout_stamp
    ORDER BY screated DESC LIMIT 15", 
    array(':logout_stamp' => $logout_stamp))->fetchAll();
```

Now use the new field in your if condition:

```
$link_type = ($result->link_type == 'comment') ? "comment" : "status";
```